# Socket.io not removing listener from every react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

i want to make `off` method from socket.io client to remove all match running listeners from all react components Because currently i'm listening to a same event on two different component , both are in componentDidMount,

Board.js

```
 socket.on('achievement', (data) => {
                const updateAchievement= [data, ...this.state.getAchievements];
                this.setState({
                    recentAchievements: this.state.recentAchievements.concat(data),
                    getAchievements: updateAchievement
                });
            });
```

Dashboard.js

```
 socket.on('achievement', (data) => {
                const updateAchievement= [data, ...this.state.getAchievements];
                this.setState({
                    recentAchievements: this.state.recentAchievements.concat(data),
                    getAchievements: updateAchievement
                });
            });
```

Currently if the end-user turn off listening to the event while on DashBoard.js , the Board.js is still actively receiving data which i don't want. The board.js component is always on the view that's why i can see the data still coming.

How i unsubscribe

DashBoard.js

```
componentWillUnmount(){
            socket.off("achievement");
     }
```

Like i said above, the Board component is always in the view and i can still see data coming in.

How can i stop this?

Comment: Where and how do you unsubscribe to the handlers?

Comment: @heydude101 You need to provide the handler that you want to unsubscribe. Just `'achievement'` is not enough to provide to `off()` as there are multiple handlers listening to that event. See my answer.

Comment: Just like @trinx said in his answer, You are not using the correct signature for the function. The correct one is: socket.off(eventName, functionTo UnsubscribeFrom) Since you are not supplying the second argument no handler gets removed

Comment: I'm not really using any function i just put the listener inside didMount, but i followed trixn answer and still doing the same thing,.

Comment: @heydude101 It is not clear what you are asking for. You want to remove all listeners on a users action?

Comment: Even i unmount from dashboard component the board component still listens to the same event and still receiving data...

Comment: @heydude101 Then your `Board` component must be unmounting and mounting again after you removed all handlers. Otherwise its handler must have been removed by your call to `socket.off("achievement")`.

Comment: @heydude101 How can it affect multiple users? This is a client application running in a browser?

Comment: Disregard my previous comment it was my mistake, still yielding same result sorry

Comment: I am logged on two different users, one with unmounted dashboard and the other isn't , when new achievement comes in the unmounted user still receives data..

Comment: If you call `socket.off("achievement")` **all handlers will be removed from that event**. If any component is still listening to that event after that it means that it must have been unmounted and mounted again so that it subscribes again.

Comment: A react app can only be a single user application. There is nothing like multi-user in a browser.

Comment: It is still very unclear what you want. First you said you want all components to unsubscribe, now you say that you want other components to still stay subscribed. Please be precise in your description of the problem.

Comment: The Board can't be unmounted as it always in the view (rendered), Also i check on the unmount and mounting cycles their normal.

Comment: @ trixn sorry for the misunderstanding i only want the user who unmounted not to receive data from Board, my problem is if the other user triggers achievement the data still comes in.

Comment: What do you mean with "the data still comes in"? Of course the socket does not differenciate users. If an 'achievement' event is received it is displayed by all `achievement` handlers. The socket doesn't know any users.

Comment: I'm still receiving data from server in Board component even though i already unsubscribed from the event when i unmounted from Dashboard component.

Comment: @heydude101 Calling `off()` does not stop data delivery. It only stops handling of it. So in the network tab of your inspection tool you will still see the data coming in. It will just not be handled.

Comment: "I'm still receiving data from server in Board component even though i already unsubscribed from the event when i unmounted from Dashboard component." This just can't be correct. It means that any component did call `on()` **after** the `Dashboard` was unmounted.

Comment: I only have `on` in board and dashboard, the board is not re-mounting, unmounting like you said, i don't know what's the problem.

Comment: Sorry but I will give up at this point because it is next to impossible to understand your problem without any further details. I can only tell you that calling `off('achievement')` will remove **every** handler that was previously added in the entire application. If you still see handlers being called after that it must mean that `on()` was called again.

Answer (score 6):

Just use the [`componentWillUnmout()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount) lifecycle method to call `socket.off()` with the handler. Note that `off()` requires the previously subscribed handler to be passed as the second argument:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    updateAchievement = data => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
                    recentAchievements: [...prevState.recentAchievements, data],
                    getAchievements: [data, ...prevState.getAchievements]
        }));
    }

    componentDidMount() {
       socket.on('achievement', this.updateAchievement);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
       socket.off('achievement', this.updateAchievement);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Note that you should not use `this.state` when updating the state. Always use the version of `setState` that takes a function where the first argument is the previous state and update based on that.

Comment: I followed this answer still doing the same thing

Comment: You need to do this in both components to stop listening on both components. Please update your question to include the new code